# How to make Sendkeys only send when a valid input is selected?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I have a program with a timer which sends the message "Test" each second via sendkeys, and I have it setup to where it will sendkeys 5 times, then disable the timer!

But I'm wondering if there is a way to only make it send the message if a valid input for it is selected, because it keeps trying to sendkeys when I don't have an input selected(EG: Notepad), and that is not really the desired result!

Comment: Try to add some reference/sample code which would help people to get in context.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your situation, but you can check to see if the active control is what you expect it to be by calling

If Screen.ActiveControl.Name <> "MyControl> Then ...
End If

before the  SendKeys is executed. You can also set the focus to a control you need it to be focused to with:

Me!YourControlName.SetFocus